# C++ memory address and offset writing / read

Tags: c++, memory, offset

Hello sorry for my bad English.
I want to calculate an address with offset.

The example I have got a base address: 0x00D2038  with offset 0x1c

I have tried this.

```
DWORD address = 0x004D2038;
DWORD offset = 0x1c;

DWORD base = (DWORD)(address + offset);
int old_value = 0;
int value = 3000;

//Obtain new address form the address whit offset.
DWORD addr2 =  ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)base,&old_value,sizeof(old_value),0);

//Write Memory
WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)addr2,&value,(DWORD)sizeof(value),NULL);
```

But it does not work.
Memory is not changed. what is my error?

Comment: Call `GetLastError` to determine why this happens.

Comment: Using DWORDs for pointer manipulation? That's just asking for trouble

Comment: @Voo Now are ok. Work. I Have solved whit this:   ReadProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)address + offset,&val,sizeof(val),0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you have a simple typo -- Try;

```
//Write Memory
WriteProcessMemory(phandle,(void*)base,&value,(DWORD)sizeof(value),NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to msdn, ReadProcessMemory returns a BOOL and you use that as addr2 to WriteProcessMemory. How can the memory be changed?

Suggest search from msdn on ReadProcessMemory and WriteProcessMemory and their example and learn how to use these 2 functions.